# How to find if a web page has a provision for users to post comments on it from its source code?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to write a python script which will be able to tell if a web page has a comment box on it or not. However different sites use different tags/classes for their comment boxes and I am not able to find a generalized tag/string to help me determine if there is a comment box on the page or not. Is there any way to find a generalized way to search for comment boxes on any given web page?

PS: I am using the requests and beautifulSoup libraries as of now. I am open to other learn libraries if they can get the work done though!

Comment: you could try searching firstly for inputs of the right type, and then filter those down by name or size, but as you stated the developer could have named them anything so this would be far from foolproof. i don't think there is any perfect way to do this

Comment: Could you please elaborate "inputs of right type"? I thought of going for forms or textareas, but again the uses of textareas is infinite for taking inputs. How to determine if it is a comment box

Comment: html input tag has a `type` attribute, this can be many things such as number, text, range etc that completely change the appearance and purpose of the element. you need to find all `input` tags of a suitable type such as `text`. There is no proper way of finding out if it is a comment box because there is no standard for what makes something a comment box. all you can do is look at the element id or name to see if you think it is, such as seeing if it contains the text "comment" thats the best you can do. however if you do some manual checking you will probably find some common naming theme